# Changes required in dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I have a perfectly running code where I have 3 sheets:

Input sheet:

[image]

Sheet2 consist of the following data :

[image]

And the output sheet :

[image]

My code goes like this :

```
Sub CommandButton1()

    Dim rngFirstTable As Excel.Range
    Dim rngSecondTable As Excel.Range
    Dim dicFilter   As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dicTasks    As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim rngInspect  As Excel.Range
    Dim lngRowSource As Long
    Dim lngRowDest  As Long
    Dim rngDisplayTopLeft As Range
    Dim rngDisplay  As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("A2:F65536").Clear
    lngRowDest = 1
    With Sheets("Input")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            .Range("E" & i).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value & "-" & .Range("D" & i).Value
        Next i
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        LastRow1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns(3).Insert shift:=xlShiftRight
        For i = 2 To LastRow1
            .Range("C" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value & "-" & .Range("B" & i).Value
        Next i
    End With

    Set rngFirstTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    Set rngSecondTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C" & LastRow1)
    Set rngDisplayTopLeft = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("A2")
    Set rngDisplay = rngDisplayTopLeft

    '   Set dictionary up containing Key's of the HR Roles
    For Each rngInspect In rngSecondTable.Columns(3).Cells
        If dicFilter.Exists(rngInspect.Value) Then
            dicFilter(rngInspect.Value).Add _
                                            CStr(dicTasks.Count + 1), _
                                            rngInspect.Offset(0, 1).Value

        Else
            Set dicTasks = New Scripting.Dictionary
            dicTasks.Add "1", rngInspect.Offset(0, 1).Value
            dicFilter.Add rngInspect.Value, dicTasks

        End If
    Next rngInspect

    For lngRowSource = 2 To rngFirstTable.Rows.Count

        '   Copy the "header info" columns
        rngDisplay.Resize(1, 4).Value = rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value

        '   Extract the relevant dictionary corresponding to HR Role HR Position

        Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 5).Value)

        '   Use the array from .items() to transpose to array equiv to range
        rngDisplay.Offset(0, 4).Resize(dicTasks.Count, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(dicTasks.Items())

        '   Increment the offset from the top left cell
        lngRowDest = lngRowDest + dicTasks.Count
        Set rngDisplay = rngDisplayTopLeft.Offset(lngRowDest - 1, 0)

        Set dicTasks = Nothing

    Next lngRowSource
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E:E").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(3).Delete
    End Sub
```

Logic : 
What my code does is :

- concatenates SubFunction & HR Position from Input sheet(adds new column in E)
- concatenates SubFucntion & HR position from Sheet2(adds new column after B)
- stores new Column C from Sheet2 in a dictionary as key and search in new Column D in Input
- returns corresponding user,comp code,subfunction,HR position,Task/role in Output sheet

New requirement:
What if a user doesnot have subfunction?
Eg :

[image]

In this case, the dictionary should store keys for Column B in Sheet2 and search it in D column in Input sheet
and then it should return all corresponding Task/role of Quality technician in Output sheet irrespective of subfunction and subfunction should show blank in Output sheet

Description of error :
I am facing an error at line:

```
Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 5).Value)
```

so,it shud be like :

```
Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 5).Value) '--> in case subfunction is there and,
Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 4).Value) '--> in case subfunction is not there
```

Similarly,

```
For Each rngInspect In rngSecondTable.Columns(3).Cells '--> in case subfunction is there and, 

For Each rngInspect In rngSecondTable.Columns(2).Cells '--> in case subfunction is not there
```

How can I merge both logic into one?

Comment: What happened when you did that though?  Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: @TimWilliams : Hello Tim. Thanku fr taking interest.
I am facing an error at line:
Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 5).Value)

so,it shud be like :
Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 5).Value) in case subfunction is there and,
Set dicTasks = dicFilter(rngFirstTable.Cells(lngRowSource, 4).Value) in case subfunction is not there
Similarly, 
For Each rngInspect In rngSecondTable.Columns(3).Cells in case of subfunction is there and,
For Each rngInspect In rngSecondTable.Columns(2).Cells in case subfunction is not there
How can merge both?

Comment: Please update your post to add code/details - it's difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: @TimWilliams : I have done the editing part. Please check

Comment: see my edit below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a different approach but easier to manage/adapt I think

EDIT: If you want each row to be fully-populated then move the `rwOut.Cells(1).Resize(1, 4).Value = ...` line to inside the `For rwRole = 1 To UBound(RoleData, 1)` loop

```
Sub CommandButton1()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim UserData, RoleData, rwOut As Range, rwUser As Long, rwRole As Long
    Dim subFunc, hrPos

    Set rwOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("A2:E2")
    rwOut.Resize(70000).Clear

    UserData = TableData(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("A1"))
    RoleData = TableData(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"))

    For rwUser = 1 To UBound(UserData, 1)
        subFunc = UserData(rwUser, 3)
        hrPos = UserData(rwUser, 4)
        rwOut.Cells(1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(UserData(rwUser, 1), _
                                    UserData(rwUser, 2), subFunc, hrPos)
        For rwRole = 1 To UBound(RoleData, 1)
            'check for match on both, or on HRPos+empty subfunction
            If RoleData(rwRole, 2) = hrPos And _
              (RoleData(rwRole, 1) = subFunc Or Len(subFunc) = 0) Then
                rwOut.Cells(5).Value = RoleData(rwRole, 3)
                Set rwOut = rwOut.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next rwRole
    Next rwUser

End Sub

'utility to get table range from contained cell, without headers
'assumes no fully-empty rows or columns
Function TableData(c As Range)
    With c.CurrentRegion
        TableData = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Value
    End With
End Function
```